# sidebar fixed only on screen size > 992px and above still not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a sidebar whose position is fixed only when the screen size is `992px and above`. I've made the sidebar position fixed, but when the screen is 991 down the position is still fixed. I want when the screen size is 991px and down the position is relative.

but when i refresh the page, it works normally. Is there a strange behavior with the use of this javascript code?

Anyone can help me to solved this problem?

```
if ($(window).width() >= 992) {
    var theLoc = 150;
    var links = $('.d-submenu');
    var content = $('.main-content');
                    
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        console.log('scroll');
        if (theLoc >= $(window).scrollTop()) {
            if (links.hasClass('fixed')) {
                links.removeClass('fixed');
                content.removeClass('fixed');

             }
         } else {
             if (!links.hasClass('fixed')) {
                 links.addClass('fixed');
                 content.addClass('fixed');
             }
          }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a event listener for page resize something like

```
   $(window).on('resize', function(){
     var win = $(this); //this = window
     if (win.width() >= 992) { /* ... */ }
   });
```

EDIT FOR FULL SOLUTION

```
    function screenResize() {
     if ($(window).width() >= 992) {
        var theLoc = 150;
        var links = $('.d-submenu');
        var content = $('.main-content');
    } REST OF YOUR CODE
```

// On page load call

```
    screenResize();
```

// And recheck when window gets resized.

```
    $(window).on('resize',function(){
        screenResize();
    });
```

Comment: I've used your code above, but my code just works when the window is resized

Comment: @Frauds I don't think your question is clear on what you are trying to achieve. You are saying when you refresh the page it doesn't work? or when you resize the page?

Comment: before i use your code, the code work after i refresh the code, before i refresh the code the code not work. After i used your code, the code work just when i resize the window